# Navbar does not appear when the file is saved in a nested folder

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap: my navbar code does not appear when a copy of the same file is saved in a different folder, even though the code is exactly the same
Bootstrap: I have tried looking for an answer to this question on the net but I cannot find the answer.

Here is my code that works.  It is located in file:///C:/Users/Spiridon/Desktop/bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/index-1.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">


    </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Navbar does not appear when I run a copy of the same file from another folder. Same code, but from this folder:
file:///C:/Users/Spiridon/Desktop/bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/index/index-1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By moving your page to a nested folder you've broken the relative paths to your prerequisites. For example,

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

needs to be

```
<link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

in the second folder.